# HandleSignInResult = false when trying to Google sign in

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I followed [this google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) and I just copy and pasted the whole SignInActivity with xml files and some string resources that were needed.
But everytime when I try to sign in from the emulator in the LogCat it shows `handleSignInResult: false`. I've been trying to get the google sign in to work for about a week now so I could setup my Achievements and Leaderboard. I really hope that someone could help me to solve this huge headache.

EDIT: That part where you have to choose your email to sign in was working, but the actual sign in not.

EDIT: I got the release key SHA 1 and added the json file to my app/ module, but still even after it has shown me which email to pick to sign in I click on one and it still doesn't connect!!!

EDIT: I JUST 4 seconds ago saved the edit and after that IT WORKED!!!!:D:D:D:D!!!!!! And just in case if anyone sees this and has problems with SHA1 then download [this](http://www.keystore-explorer.org/) program, it's much easier then getting a headache from the freaking terminal/cmd. And now I'm off to celebrate my win against the evil Google Sign in. Oh and I got it working on my phone and it's still not working on the emulator, but that's not a problem.

Comment: Try your device? The emulator might not have play services.

Comment: The emulator definetely has the services because when I tried with higher version of dependency google play services: 9.2.1  it said that it needs to update and then I lowered it to 8.4.0 and then it just handleSignInResult = false.

Answer (score 0):

First check your Manifest, do you add the INTERNET permission?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, check to make sure your Gradle has all the compile commands and dependencies that are on the same page for that API

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'                                       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0'           these are the dependencies that are needed I believe.

Comment: You need to add to both the app and project Gradle files. That one is the app only (don't quote me) but you need the code for the other file as well

Comment: Follow everything on this page I'm assuming it's the Gradle error you also need to put the configuration file in your project, that could definitely be the cause of that error as well.   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: I need to give the signing certificate finger print the SHA 1, but when I do keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>      it gives me incorrect syntax error

Comment: I put my key name which I created in Android Studio by doing the "Build signed apk" and put the path where it is, but now it gives me an error: Keystore file exists but is empty???

Comment: this is the command I did:                                     keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias freenthrowkey -keystore C:\Users\User\Documents\FreeNthrowkey

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not able to help there. I use Firebase for my backend which has a copy and past SHA-1. I'll do some looking around and see what I can find for you.